# fvwmWinList missing from ubuntu 18

Tags: fvwm

Since upgrading to ubuntu 18 the module fvwmWinList seems to be missing.
I get the error-entry:

```
[fvwm][executeModule]: <<ERROR>> No such module 'FvwmWinList' in ModulePath '/usr/lib/fvwm/2.6.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WindowList command or the FvwmIconMan module instead as of Fvwm 2.6.6.

FvwmWinList passed your key strokes to the window under the pointer, so iconify, maximize, etc. bindings worked in the list as if the target had focus.  The builtin is fairly anemic but provides a double click action and a trigger function. You may want to compile the old Fvwm -- or fvwm-patched from ArchLinux -- to get better results.

I had a binding for left mouse on root to show the list:

`Mouse 3 R N Module FvwmWinList Transient`

For 2.6.6, added this line -- looks acceptable:

`Test (Version > 2.6.5) Mouse 3 R N WindowList \ 
      NoGeometry,NoCurrentDeskTitle,MaxLabelWidth 24`

Read the man page for full info -- there is a lot:

`The options passed to WindowList are separated by commas: Geometry/ NoGeometry/NoGeometryWithInfo, NoDeskNum, NoLayer, NoNumInDeskTitle, NoCurrentDeskTitle, MaxLabelWidth width, TitleForAllDesks, Function funcname, Desk desknum, CurrentDesk, NoIcons / Icons / OnlyIcons, NoNormal / Normal / OnlyNormal, NoSticky / Sticky / OnlySticky, NoStickyAcrossPages / StickyAcrossPages / OnlyStickyAcrossPages, NoStickyAcrossDesks / StickyAcrossDesks / OnlyStickyAcrossDesks, NoOnTop / OnTop / OnlyOnTop, NoOnBottom / OnBottom / OnlyOnBottom, Layer m [n], UseSkipList / OnlySkipList, NoDeskSort, ReverseOrder, CurrentAtEnd, IconifiedAtEnd, UseIconName, Alphabetic / NotAlphabetic, SortByResource, SortByClass, NoHotkeys, SelectOnRelease.`

Comment: yes, I've read this in several places. But no hint How To